# Date format python

Tags: python

I'm new at programming and I'm writing a program where the user gives me a date input in a format DD/MM/YYYY, but if the user writes the date in this format DD.MM.YYYY it gives me an error "not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)" because I split the input string by "/".  My question is: How can I give an error message and ask for an input again if the user writes the date in the wrong format?

ex:

```
Data1= input("Which date (DD/MM/YYYY)?\n")
day,month,year= Data1.split('/')
isValidDate= True
try :
    datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day))
except ValueError :
    isValidDate = False
if(isValidDate) :                                        
    A1=function(username, Data1)
    print ("Good",A1,".")
else :
    print ("Incorrect. New date, please (format DD/MM/YYYY)")
```

Comment: Hello, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to aid you. We cannot help without code. What have you tried? SO is very willing to help solve a specific coding problem.

Comment: Can you add your code to this question? What have you tried..?

Comment: Have you considered parsing the date with `time.strptime(data1, '%d/%m/%Y')`? The `datetime` library also provides a similar method. Another good library is `dateutil`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this i copy and paste into anything i do with date input

```
while True:
    user_date = input('please input date DD/MM/YYY:')
    if re.search(r'[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/20[0-9]{2}', user_date):
        break
    else:
        continue
```

you'll have to

```
import re
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below assert condition and it will exit your program.

```
date = input('your date :')

assert('.' in date, " Please use format MM/DD/YY")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like this.

```
while True:
    i = input("enter date")
    if i.__contains__("."):
        print("re-enter date with format YY/MM/DD ")
    else:
        print("\ndo something with Date: ", i)
        break
```

outputs:

```
enter date 2020.03.02
re-enter date with format YY/MM/DD 
enter date 2020/03/02

do something with Date:  2020/03/02
```

Based on your example, you could re-factor the code to something:

```
def parse_date(Data1):
    try :
        day, month, year= Data1.split('/')
        datetime.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day))
        A1 = function(username, Data1)
        print ("Good", A1, ".")
    except ValueError as e:
        print("Add some error message!", e)                                    

while True:
    Data1= input("Which date (DD/MM/YYYY)?\n")
    if Data1.__contains__("."):
        print ("Incorrect. New date, please (format DD/MM/YYYY)")
    else:
        parse_date(Data1)
        break
```